# Washer method confusion

Tags: calculus

Compute volume of solid created by revolving the area bounded by $y=\sqrt x$, $y=0$ $x=1$, $x=4$,  around the y axis.
I understand that I can find the volume by integration of the $A(y)$ from $0$ to $2$ since these are the $y$ values of the intercepts of $x=1$ and $x=4$.

My understanding is that I would compute the area $(A(y) $by:
$\pi$ $(R^2)-r^2)$ where $R$ is the outer radius and $r$ is the inner radius. Then I integrate this as $\int_0^2 A(y)dy$.

So, I compute the outer radius $R$ by calculating the $x$ distance from the right most boundary, in this case $x=4$ and the $y$ axis. Thus $R=4$. Is this the way to calculate $R$ even if part of the $R$ $x$ distance isn't inside the boundary?? Ugh,confused on the definition here.

The inner radius is the $x$ distance from the function to the axis of rotation (the $y$ axis).  So, $r=y^2$.

But, it I would think that this x distance is ONLY within the region of $x=1$ and $x=4$. So, since I should always calculate from right to left, wouldn't this radius be $y^2-1$?? But seems like I am using the $R$ by NOT considering the area in the bounded region and I AM using the $r$ by considering the bonded region.

I cannot seem to understand this washer problem even though I can work others and I can see that I don't fully understand the definition of how to computer the inner and outer radii.

Can someone clarify?  Bottom line is that I can't seem to be able to compute the inner and outer radii of this problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross section

[image]

---

**Shell method**

[image]

$$V = \int\limits_{r=1}^4 2 \pi r \sqrt{r} dr = \frac{124 \pi }{5}$$

---

**Washer method**

[image]

$$V = \int\limits_{z=0}^1 \pi (4^2 - 1^2)\ dz + \int\limits_{z=1}^2 \pi (4^2 - z^2)\ dz = \frac{124 \pi }{5}$$

Comment: The calculation at the bottom looks like some kind of unholy hybrid between washers and shells. Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: These are shells.

Comment: Then it should be $2\pi r$ rather than $\pi(r^2-1^2)$, namely the circumrefence of the shell at radius $r$.

Comment: Yep (+1)... thanks..

Comment: Then I only take issue with your value for the definite integral. It looks like you may have forgotten to take an antiderivative ... or something worse. (The volume of the entire circumscribed cylinder is only $32\pi$).

Comment: Ooppsss... Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: I actually AM able to work this problem using the shell method and seems much more intuitive that way.  However, the text (and instructor) indicated that some of the problems on the test would indicate that the problem must be worked given a specific method.  I'm concerned that I don't see how to do it via the washer method and if the problem states to work it that way, I don't think I'll get credit by doing it via shell.

Comment: @user163862:  See the completed solution (both ways).

Comment: Is there a reason to use the $z$ variable instead of $y$?

Comment: @user163862:  Yes.  In my casting, $x$ and $y$ are in the plane, and $z$ is the vertical.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: That's a bit misleading, since the problem explicitly stated that the axis of revolution would be the _y-axis_.

Answer (score 2):

First, draw a diagram. This step is *mandatory* and to be skipped only if you have a clear mental picture of how it will look without drawing it.

[image: diagram of the are to be rotated]

Since we're rotating about the $y$-axis the washers are horizontal sections through the shaded areas -- and the radius is just the $x$ coordinate of each point in the figure. We can see on the diagram that the range of relevant $y$s is $[0,2]$, and the inner and outer radiuses will be:

$$ {\rm inner}(y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{for }0\le y \le 1 \\ y^2 & \text{for } 1 \le y \le 2 \end{cases} \qquad \qquad {\rm outer}(y) = 4 $$

Can you take it from here?

---

By the way, the shape of the area suggests it would be much easier to compute with the shell method. You wouldn't need any piecewise defined functions and could do everything in one integral.

Comment: I did draw an image similar to yours. I got similar values for inner and outer radii and could NOT get the text answer which is 124pi/5.

Comment: Can you assist me in understanding why there are 2 inner radii?

Comment: @user163862: The left side of the shaded area consists of a straight line from $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$, and the part of the parabola between $(1,1)$ and $(4,2)$. The sharp bend in this inside edge corresponds to the switch between expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The inner radius would be $1$ for $0\leq y<1$ and $y^2$ for $1\leq y\leq2$.

The outer radius would be 4 for $0\leq y\leq2$

Then, the set up for the volume would be
$$V=\pi\int_{0}^{1}(4^2-1^2)~dy+\pi\int_{1}^{2}(4^2-y^4)~dy=\frac{124\pi}{5}$$
[image]

Comment: How on earth do you get those radiuses?

Comment: I used the graph of $x=y^2$. Since the area is bounded between x=4 and x=1, I think the outer radius should be $4-y^2$, and the inner radius should be $1-y^2$. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I'm still quite baffled where you're measuring those radii. Are you imagining we're  you're rotating about the line $x=4$? No, that doesn't make sense either. Perhaps you could draw a diagram to show more precisely where you get those distances from?

Comment: I think I made a mistake, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Henning: I have added the image. Does my answer make sense now?

Comment: x @Larry: Um ... I can see what you're doing now, but it is quite wrong. "Radius" means _distance from the axis of revolution_, and the axis of revolution is the y-axis, _not_ the red parabola! How would you rotate something about a curved axis anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I am wrong. I will try to adjust my answer.

Comment: Fixed, thank you for pointing out all my mistakes.

Comment: So, your way is the way the text does it and it completely baffles me.  First, and this is my key inability to understand this problem, WHY are there 2 inner radii? Is it because the vertical boundaries don't start until x=1 so there is no function from y=0 to y=1?